# Extract a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data set :

[image]

and I want to extract a new dataframe of the following form :

[image]

I tried this code but I got "NaN" for all cells

```
years = list(df_le["Year"].unique())
df2 =pd.DataFrame()
df2["Country"] =list(df_le["Country"].unique())
for year in years :
   df2[year] = df_le[df_le["Year"]==year]["Life expectancy "]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df.pivot(index='Country', columns='Year', values='Life expectancy').reset_index()
```